# ProgressDialog : Don't Dismissing after showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
    private void copyFile(AppDB apkfile) {
    ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.show(this,"Coping ...",apkfile.name,true,true);
    File f1 = new File(apkfile.location);
    try {
        String fileName = apkfile.name;
        File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "Easy Share");
        f2.mkdirs();
        f2 = new File(f2.getPath() + "/" + fileName + ".apk");
        f2.createNewFile();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    if(pd.isShowing()) {
   pd.dismiss();}

}
```

Hi everyone when trying to dismiss the progress dialog it wont do that and serarched for many solution but i not its same Problem.
please help.

Update: there is Progress Dialog pd's class after running.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no there are no errors

Comment: You can call `AlertDialog#dismiss` on the `AlertDialog` which is returned by `AlertDialog.Builder#create`

Comment: I tried alert Dialog as you say but not worked

Comment: When i debug it i found that the pd is showing every thing null after showing.

Comment: pd.show(this,"Coping ...",apkfile.name); use only this much instead pd.show(this,"Coping ...",apkfile.name,true,true);

Comment: put a debug point for this line if(pd.isShowing())  , and check the control comes here or not , if it comes here then as u said pd = null after showing the dialog , it should hit with a NullPointerException...pls check and let meknow..

Comment: i did it before you say and add the image to post. and all its null what i suppose to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585759/cant-dismiss-progressdialog-after-the-asynctask-complete

Comment: refer this link and try implementing the same

Comment: before u make any changes try making ProgressDialog "final", as below  final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

Comment: final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

Comment: know its not showing dialog even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy should be done in a Thread or a AsyncTask. Show the dialog before executing the AsyncTask and hide in the onPOstExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
       if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
          mProgressDialog.dismiss();}
       }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man i finally solved it With AsyncTask. I used this Tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try with `finally`

```
private void copyFile(AppDB apkfile) {
    ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.show(this,"Coping ...",apkfile.name,true,true);
    File f1 = new File(apkfile.location);
    try {
        String fileName = apkfile.name;
        File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "Easy Share");
        f2.mkdirs();
        f2 = new File(f2.getPath() + "/" + fileName + ".apk");
        f2.createNewFile();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } finally {
      if(pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.dismiss();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working well i will tell you two possibilities

1. please use it in try block at last as

   ```
   try {
       String fileName = apkfile.name;
       File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "Easy Share");
       f2.mkdirs();
       f2 = new File(f2.getPath() + "/" + fileName + ".apk");
       f2.createNewFile();
       InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
       OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       int len;
       while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
           out.write(buf, 0, len);
       }
       in.close();
       out.close();
      if(pd.isShowing()) {
      pd.dismiss();}
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   }
   ```

   }

second is
use in delay